# How to change Background color of UITabbar selected tab color to blue?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

[image]

Hi,
   I wanted this kind of Tab Selection effect. Instead of Black Background it should be blue one.Is it possible that when i select any tab it should come up with blue background.Please guide me what should i do?I have tried so much but not getting any proper solution.Please suggest me what should i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `tintColor:` property of UITabBar:

```
myTabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

note this only works on iOS5.

**EDIT:**

oops! sorry i misunderstood your question. I thought you meant the background color of the whole tab bar.

For that you can add an image for background of the selection using `selectionIndicatorImage` property:

```
myTabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

hope this helps

Comment: @KDaker- what if I want to change the background icon of the whole tab item at selection?